# JTree D&D DataFlavor issue (NotSerializableException in some cases)

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree, notserializableexception

I'm implementing D&D for a `JTree`. I have written a custom `TransferHandler` and created a new `Transferable` class. This class is very easy:

```
public class TreePathTransferable implements Transferable{

  private static final DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[] {
          new DataFlavor(TreePath[].class,"TreePaths")};

  private TreePath[] data;

  public TreePathTransferable(TreePath[] data) {
    super();
    this.data = data;
  }

  public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
    return flavors;
  }

  public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
    return flavors[0].equals(flavor);
  }

  public TreePath[] getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws
          UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException{
    return data;
  }
}
```

If "on drop" I call

```
dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferDataFlavors()[0])
```

I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException`. If I change class of the data-object in `TreePathTransferable` to `Object` in the following way:

```
public class TreePathTransferable implements Transferable{

  private static final DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[] {
          new DataFlavor(Object.class,"Object")};

  private Object data;

  public TreePathTransferable(Object data) {
    super();
    this.data = data;
  }

  public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
    return flavors;
  }

  public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
    return flavors[0].equals(flavor);
  }

  public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws
          UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException{
    return data;
  }

}
```

Everything works fine. This makes no sense for me since transferred data are same - `TreePath[]`.  Why the difference?

**Stack trace**

Note: I have replaced the non-serializable class with XXX. This is a property of a subclass of DefaultMutableTreeNode. This subclass is not serializable, so the Exception is meaningful, but why she doesn't appear in the second case?

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: XXX
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
    at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Vector.java:1077)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.TransferableProxy.getTransferData(TransferableProxy.java:83)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy.getTransferData(DropTargetContext.java:376)
```

**TransferHandler**

```
public class MyTreeTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
  public MyTreeTransferHandler() {
    super();
  }

  protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
    Transferable t = null;
    if(c instanceof JTree) {
      JTree tree = (JTree) c;
        t = new TreePathTransferable(tree.getSelectionPaths());
        return t;
    }
    return t;
  }

  public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
    return TransferHandler.MOVE;
  }

  public boolean canImport(JComponent c, DataFlavor[] flavors){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I added a question *"Why the difference?"*.  If that is **not** the question, please ask your own (specific) question.

Comment: I'm not getting any exception.Can you post your `TransferHandler` class.

Comment: There is no problem with the code and what is the XXX class.and read abt [Serialization](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-io-notserializableexception-how-to-solve-not-serializable-exception/)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600213/why-doesnt-java-lang-object-implement-the-serializable-interface)

Comment: And when replying to someperson always use @SanthoshKumarTekuri or @ whoever the person is to notify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is caused by three things:

1. You used DataFlavor constructor where you do not directly specify to not serialize transferred data. It is kind of indirect anyway (see [DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.datatransfer/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19568556/1651107))
2. D&D mechanism tries to serialize transferred data if it can. Reason is: "This insulates applications sharing DnD and Clipboard data from each other".
3. D&D mechanism checks if it can serialize data by checking class you provided in DataFlavor constructor, not runtime class of object transferred.

Following your stacktrace, this can be seen in [TransferableProxy source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/awt/datatransfer/TransferableProxy.java):

```
public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor df)
        throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
    {
        Object data = transferable.getTransferData(df);
        // If the data is a Serializable object, then create a new instance
        // before returning it. This insulates applications sharing DnD and
        // Clipboard data from each other.
        if (data != null && isLocal && df.isFlavorSerializedObjectType()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ClassLoaderObjectOutputStream oos =
                new ClassLoaderObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(data);
            ByteArrayInputStream bais =
                new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            try {
                ClassLoaderObjectInputStream ois =
                    new ClassLoaderObjectInputStream(bais,
                                                     oos.getClassLoaderMap());
                data = ois.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {

                throw (IOException)new IOException().initCause(cnfe);
            }
        }
        return data;
}
```

Important part is `df.isFlavorSerializedObjectType()`. [This calls](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.java) `isRepresentationClassSerializable` method implemented as `return java.io.Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(representationClass);`.

So this compares Class you provided in `DataFlavor` constructor to `Serializable` interface. Since `TreePath[].class` [implements Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) and [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) does not, serialization is not performed for `Object` class (Using `new DataFlavor(Object.class,"Object")` constructor call).