# Using Drag and Drop in Solitaire Game for Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drag-and-drop

so I'm creating a Solitaire game in Java. I have the card, deck, and most of the GUI coded out. However, when I go to implement drag and drop into the GUI, I am able to drag the cards to a different tableau stack, but when I drop it, it just pastes the card on the card that was previously there instead of stacking it on it. Plus, the card is not removed from its old location. How would you resolve this?

I have tried using exportAsDrag(jc,e,TransferHandler.MOVE); and added code to make it run, but that didn't seem to work either.

here are the three classes (Solitaire class is the GUI one):

```
//imports
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Solitaire extends JFrame {
    
    //instance variables
    private static final int CARD_WIDTH = 73;
    private static final int CARD_HEIGHT = (int)(CARD_WIDTH*1.49137931+.5);
    private static final int TOP_STACKS_X_DIFF = 435;
    private static final int TOP_STACKS_Y_DIFF = 30;
    private static final int WASTE_STACK_X_DIFF = 139;
    private static final int WASTE_STACK_Y_DIFF = 30;
    private static final int MAIN_STACKS_X_DIFF = 30;
    private static final int MAIN_STACKS_Y_DIFF = 40;
        
    private final JLabel newStack;
    private final JLabel wasteStack;
    private final JLabel[] topStacks;
    private final JLayeredPane[] mainStacks;
    
    private Card wasteCard;
    
    private Deck deckOfCards;
    
    //methods
    /**
     * Creates new form gameScreenGUI
     */
    public Solitaire() {
        //setting up JFrame
        setTitle("Solitaire");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,153,0));
        
        //Create the topStacks
        topStacks = new JLabel[4]; //initializing topStacks
        for (int index = 0; index < topStacks.length; index++) { //loop through to create stack for each suit
            topStacks[index] = new JLabel(); //creating new stack
            topStacks[index].setBounds((index*CARD_WIDTH) + (index*10) + TOP_STACKS_X_DIFF, TOP_STACKS_Y_DIFF, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT); //creating the boundary for each top stack
            topStacks[index].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)); //setting the border for each top stack
            add(topStacks[index]); //adding to GUI
        } //end of for loop
        
        //Create the wasteStack
        wasteStack = new JLabel(); //initializing wasteStack
        wasteStack.setBounds(WASTE_STACK_X_DIFF, WASTE_STACK_Y_DIFF, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT); //creating the boundary for the waste stack
        wasteStack.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)); //setting the border for the boundary of the waste stack
        add(wasteStack); //adding to GUI
        
        //Create the newStack
        newStack = new JLabel(); //initializing newStack
        newStack.setBounds(WASTE_STACK_X_DIFF - CARD_WIDTH - 36, WASTE_STACK_Y_DIFF, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT); //creating the boundary for the new stack
        newStack.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)); //setting the border for the boundary of the new stack
        newStack.addMouseListener(new newStackOnClick()); //adding event
        add(newStack); //adding to GUI
        
        //Create the mainStacks
        mainStacks = new JLayeredPane[7]; //initializing mainStacks
        for (int index = 0; index < mainStacks.length; index++) { //loop through to create 7 stacks
            mainStacks[index] = new JLayeredPane(); //creating new stack
            mainStacks[index].setBounds((index*CARD_WIDTH) + (index*36) + MAIN_STACKS_X_DIFF, MAIN_STACKS_Y_DIFF + (CARD_HEIGHT + 10), CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT); //creating the boundary for each main stack
            mainStacks[index].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK)); //setting the border for each main stack
            add(mainStacks[index]); //add to GUI
        } //end of for loop

        
        setLayout(null); //changing to null layout
        setSize(800, 600); //defining size of window
        setVisible(true); //displaying window
        startGame(); //starts the game
    } //end of constructor method
    
    /**
     * This method creates the game.
     */
    private void startGame() {
        //creates and shuffles a new deck
        deckOfCards = new Deck();
        deckOfCards.shuffleDeck();
        
        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                JComponent jc = (JComponent)e.getSource();
                TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
                th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            
        };

        
        for (int stack = 0; stack < mainStacks.length; stack++) { //loop through the stacks in the mainStacks
            int stackHeight = 0; //stores the height of the stack
            
            for (int cardInStack = 0; cardInStack <= stack; cardInStack++) { //loop through to add the cards in each Stack
                Card placementCard = deckOfCards.drawCard(); //draws card
                placementCard.setIsFaceUp(false);
                //checking if the card is the last card in the stack
                if (stack == cardInStack) {
                    placementCard.setIsFaceUp(true); //card is facing up
                    //sizes the image and sets it to placementCard
                    ImageIcon placementCardFace = new ImageIcon(placementCard.getImagePath());
                    Image placementCardScaled = placementCardFace.getImage().getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    JLabel cardLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(placementCardScaled));
                    cardLabel.setBounds(0,cardInStack*22, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
                    cardLabel.addMouseListener(ml);
                    cardLabel.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    mainStacks[stack].add(cardLabel, Integer.valueOf(cardInStack));
                } //end of if statement
                
                //if statement to check whether the card should be revealed or not
                if (!placementCard.getIsFaceUp()) { //hide cardFront
                    //sizes the image and sets it to placementCard
                    ImageIcon placementCardBack = new ImageIcon(Card.getBackImagePath());
                    Image placementCardScaled = placementCardBack.getImage().getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    JLabel cardLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(placementCardScaled));
                    cardLabel.setBounds(0,cardInStack*22, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
                    mainStacks[stack].add(cardLabel, Integer.valueOf(cardInStack));
                } //end of if statement
                
                stackHeight = CARD_HEIGHT + (22*stack); //increments the stack height with each new card
                
            } //end of for loop
            
            mainStacks[stack].setSize(CARD_WIDTH, stackHeight); //sets the size of the stack so that all cards show
            
        } //end of for loop
        
        //sizes the image and sets it to newCard
        ImageIcon cardBack = new ImageIcon(Card.getBackImagePath());
        Image cardBackScaled = cardBack.getImage().getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        newStack.setIcon(new ImageIcon(cardBackScaled));
        
        wasteCard = deckOfCards.drawCard(); //new card from pile to possibly add to mainStacks
        wasteCard.setIsFaceUp(true); //sets card facing up        
        
        //sizes the image and sets it to wasteCard
        ImageIcon wasteCardFace = new ImageIcon(wasteCard.getImagePath());
        Image wasteCardFaceScaled = wasteCardFace.getImage().getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        wasteStack.addMouseListener(ml);
        wasteStack.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
        wasteStack.setIcon(new ImageIcon(wasteCardFaceScaled));
                
    } //end of startGame method
    
    private void newStackClick() {
        if(!deckOfCards.isEmpty()) {
            wasteCard = deckOfCards.drawCard();
            System.out.println(wasteCard);
            wasteCard.setIsFaceUp(true);
            
            ImageIcon wasteCardFace = new ImageIcon(wasteCard.getImagePath());
            Image wasteCardScaled = wasteCardFace.getImage().getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            wasteStack.setIcon(new ImageIcon(wasteCardScaled));
        } else {
            resetNewStack();
        } //end of if statement
    } //end of newStackClick method
    
    private void resetNewStack() {
        deckOfCards.resetDrawCardIndex();
        deckOfCards.shuffleDeck();
        wasteCard = deckOfCards.drawCard();
        wasteCard.setIsFaceUp(true);
        
        ImageIcon wasteCardFace = new ImageIcon(wasteCard.getImagePath());
        Image wasteCardScaled = wasteCardFace.getImage().getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        wasteStack.setIcon(new ImageIcon(wasteCardScaled));
        
        ImageIcon cardBack = new ImageIcon(Card.getBackImagePath());
        Image cardBackScaled = cardBack.getImage().getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        newStack.setIcon(new ImageIcon(cardBackScaled));
    } //end of resetNewStack method
    
    private class newStackOnClick extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            newStackClick();
        } //end of mouseClicked method
    } //end of newStackOnClick class

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solitaire();
    } //end of main method

} //end of SolitaireJLP class
```

```
public class Card {
    //instance variables
    private final Suit SUIT;
    private final Rank RANK;
    private boolean isFaceUp;
    
    //methods
    /**
     * This is the constructor method for the Card class.
     * @param suit - the suit to be assigned to the card.
     * @param rank - the rank to be assigned to the card.
     */
    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.SUIT = suit;
        this.RANK = rank;
        this.isFaceUp = false;
    } //end of constructor
    
    /**
     * This method gives the user the suit of the Card.
     * @return Suit - the suit of the Card.
     */
    public Suit getSuit() {
        return this.SUIT;
    } //end of getSuit method
    /**
     * This method gives the user the rank of the Card.
     * @return Rank - the rank of the Card.
     */
    public Rank getRank() {
        return this.RANK;
    } //end of getRank method
    
    /**
     * This method gives whether the Card is faced up or not.
     * @return Boolean - true or false based on if the Card is facing up.
     */
    public boolean getIsFaceUp() {
        return this.isFaceUp;
    } //end of getIsFaceUp method
    /**
     * This method sets the isFaceUp variable to true if the card is facing up in the game.
     */
    public void setIsFaceUp(boolean b) {
        this.isFaceUp = b;
    } //end of setIsFaceUp method
    
    /**
     * This method determines if the Card is from a red suit.
     * @return Boolean - true or false if card is red
     */
    public boolean isRed() {
        return this.SUIT == Suit.HEARTS || this.SUIT == Suit.DIAMONDS;
    } //end of isRed method
    /**
     * This method determines if the Card is from a black suit.
     * @return a Boolean true or false if card is black
     */
    public boolean isBlack() {
        return this.SUIT == Suit.CLUBS || this.SUIT == Suit.SPADES;
    } //end of isBlack method
    
    /**
     * This method determines if the card can be stacked on the card behind it.
     * @return a Boolean true or false if it can be stacked
     */
    public boolean stackable(Card card) {
        return this.isRed() != card.isRed();
    } //end of stackable method
    
    /**
     * This method gives the name of each card.
     * @return a string that has two letters- the first letter of the rank and the first letter of the suit.
     */
    public String getName() {
        String number = ""; //variable declaration
        switch(RANK) { //switch to assign rank name
            case ACE -> number = "A"; //case
            case TWO -> number = "2"; //case
            case THREE -> number = "3"; //case
            case FOUR -> number = "4"; //case
            case FIVE -> number = "5"; //case
            case SIX -> number = "6"; //case
            case SEVEN -> number = "7"; //case
            case EIGHT -> number = "8"; //case
            case NINE -> number = "9"; //case
            case TEN -> number = "10"; //case
            case JACK -> number = "J"; //case
            case QUEEN -> number = "Q"; //case
            case KING -> number = "K"; //case
        } //end of switch
        String suitName = ""; //variable declaration
        switch(SUIT) { //switch to assign suit name
            case HEARTS -> suitName = "H"; //case
            case DIAMONDS -> suitName = "D"; //case
            case SPADES -> suitName = "S"; //case
            case CLUBS -> suitName = "C"; //case
        } //end of switch
        return number + suitName; //return statement
    } //end of getName method
    
    /**
     * This method gives the path to a corresponding image.
     * @return String - returns the path of the image corresponding with the card.
     */
    public String getImagePath() {
        return "C:\\ICS3U_SUMMATIVE_SOLITAIRE\\src\\cards\\" + getName().substring(1,getName().length()) + "\\" + getName() + ".jpg"; //return statement
    } //end of getImage method
    /**
     * This method gives the file path to the back of the card image.
     * @return String the file path to the card back image
     */
    public static String getBackImagePath() {
        return "C:\\ICS3U_SUMMATIVE_SOLITAIRE\\src\\CardBack.jpg";
    } //end of getImageBackPath method
    
    @Override
    /**
     * This method returns the description about the instance variables.
     * @return String - rank and suit of card along with image path.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return this.RANK + " of " + this.SUIT + " ---- " + getImagePath();
    }
} //end of Card class
```

```
//imports
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck {
    
    //instance variables
    private final ArrayList<Card> cards;
    private int drawCardIndex;
    
    //methods
    /**
     * This constructor for the Deck class creates all 52 cards and adds them to cards List.
     */
    public Deck() {
        cards = new ArrayList<>(); //creating new deck
        
        for (Suit suit: Suit.values()) { //loops through suits
            for (Rank rank: Rank.values()) { //loops through ranks
                cards.add(new Card(suit, rank)); //adds a unique Card to cards
            }
        }
        drawCardIndex = 0; //initializes index
    } //end of constructor
    
    /**
     * This method returns the size of the deck.
     * @return int - size of deck
     */
    public int getSize() {
        return cards.size();
    } //end of getSize method
    
    /**
     * This method returns a drawn card in the deck of cards.
     * @return Card - a new drawn card in the deck of cards.
     */
    public Card drawCard() {
        if (drawCardIndex<cards.size()) { //checks if all of the cards have been drawn
            Card card = cards.get(drawCardIndex); //draws a card
            drawCardIndex++; //increments
            return card; //return statement
        }
        return null; //returns null if all of the cards have already been drawn
    } //end of drawCard method
    
    /**
     * This method shuffles the deck of cards.
     */
    public void shuffleDeck() {
        Collections.shuffle(cards); //mixes ArrayList
        resetDrawCardIndex(); //resets the drawCardIndex variable
    } //end of shuffleDeck method
    
    /**
     * This method resets the drawCardIndex.
     */
    public void resetDrawCardIndex() {
        drawCardIndex = 0;
    } //end of resetDrawCardIndex method
    
    /**
     * This method checks if all of the cards have been drawn.
     * @return Boolean true or false based on if all the cards have been drawn or not.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return cards.size() <= drawCardIndex;
    } //end of isEmpty method
    
} //end of Deck class
```

Comment: *but when I drop it, it just pastes the card on the card that was previously there instead of stacking it on it* - you are using a standard handler which just move the Icon from one component to another. You need to actually move the JLabel component itself, which is more involved. You can check out: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569639/131872 which creates custom handler to move a component or even a panel containing multiple components. 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811800/131872 which creates a custom MouseListener to do all the dragging.

Comment: This would need more modifications to find the proper stack to drop the component on. In both cases you would want to try using the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/). This layout manager will allow you to stack components with (or without) an offset.

Comment: @camickr i will refer to these. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @camickr so I was trying out your code and understanding how it works, but when I went to run it in my IDE, it showed an error when creating the new OverlapLayout. It said "cannot find symbol: class OverlapLayout" Is there something wrong on my end?

Comment: @PSYCHOPATH17 I provided a link to the `OverlapLayout` in the comments above.

Comment: @camickr is the overlap layout something that you coded or is it part of a library or something? Because if I use it in my code, I need to know how to cite it.

Comment: Yes, I coded it and the website says you can use it however you wish.

Comment: @camickr hey Rob Camick, I ran into another issue while coding the game, but SO isn't allowing me to put another question up for two days because of my past question quality. I think I can format this new one into a good MRE, but I am not sure how I can reach out to you or others without creating the question. Any way I can reach you besides SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using concepts from my comments above I came up with a simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DragCards extends JPanel
{
    private static DataFlavor COMPONENT_FLAVOR;

    private PanelHandler panelHandler = new PanelHandler();
    private ComponentHandler componentHandler = new ComponentHandler();
    private MouseListener dragListener;

    private Dimension cardSize = new Dimension(100, 175);

    public DragCards()
    {
        try
        {
            COMPONENT_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + ";class=\"" + Component[].class.getName() + "\"");
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

        dragListener = new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
                handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.MOVE);
            }
        };

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        add(createDeckPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(createStacksPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private JPanel createDeckPanel()
    {
        JPanel deckPanel = new JPanel( new OverlapLayout( new Point(0, 0) ) );

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            JLabel label = new JLabel( "Card: " + i );
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
            label.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );
            label.setOpaque( true );
            label.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
            label.setPreferredSize( cardSize );
            label.addMouseListener( dragListener );
            label.setTransferHandler( componentHandler );
            deckPanel.add( label );
        }

        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.add( deckPanel );

        return wrapper;
    }

    private JPanel createStacksPanel()
    {

        JPanel stackPanels = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 4, 10, 10) );
        Dimension stackDimension = new Dimension(cardSize.width, cardSize.height + 200);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            JPanel stackPanel = new JPanel( new OverlapLayout( new Point(0, 20) ) );
            stackPanel.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
            stackPanel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0) );
            stackPanel.setPreferredSize( stackDimension );
            stackPanel.setTransferHandler( panelHandler );
            stackPanels.add( stackPanel );
        }

        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.add( stackPanels );

        return (wrapper );
    }

    class ComponentHandler extends TransferHandler
    {
        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
        {
//          setDragImage( ScreenImage.createImage(c) );

            return MOVE;
        }

        @Override
        public Transferable createTransferable(final JComponent c)
        {
            return new Transferable()
            {
                @Override
                public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
                {
                    Component[] components = new Component[1];
                    components[0] = c;
                    return components;
                }

                @Override
                public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
                {
                    DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
                    flavors[0] = DragCards.COMPONENT_FLAVOR;
                    return flavors;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
                {
                    return flavor.equals(DragCards.COMPONENT_FLAVOR);
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable t, int action)
        {
        }
    }

    class PanelHandler extends TransferHandler
    {
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support)
        {
            if (!support.isDrop())
            {
                return false;
            }

            boolean canImport = support.isDataFlavorSupported(DragCards.COMPONENT_FLAVOR);
            return canImport;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport support)
        {
            if (!canImport(support))
            {
                return false;
            }

            Component[] components;

            try
            {
                components = (Component[])support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DragCards.COMPONENT_FLAVOR);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            Component component = components[0];
            Container parent = component.getParent();
            Container container = (Container)support.getComponent();
            container.add(component);

            container.getParent().revalidate();
            container.getParent().repaint();
            parent.revalidate();
            parent.repaint();

            return true;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DragCards");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new DragCards());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. If you want to set the `setDragImage(...)` method you will need to get the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) code.
2. When dragging to on of the 4 stack panels, the mouse must be on the panel, not the label. If you want the logic to work when the mouse is over a label, then (I think - but have not tried) you would need to add the import logic into the ComponentHandler class. This logic should be similar to the import logic in the panel class.

Or the second approach using custom dragging code might look something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class DragCards2 extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    private Dimension cardSize = new Dimension(100, 175);
    private JPanel deckPanel;
    private JPanel stacksPanel;

    private Component card;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;

    private MouseListener dragListener;


    public DragCards2()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add(createDeckPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(createStacksPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private JPanel createDeckPanel()
    {
        deckPanel = new JPanel( new OverlapLayout( new Point(0, 0) ) );

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            JLabel label = new JLabel( "Card: " + i );
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
            label.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );
            label.setOpaque( true );
            label.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
            label.setPreferredSize( cardSize );
            deckPanel.add( label );
        }

        deckPanel.addMouseListener( this );
        deckPanel.addMouseMotionListener( this );

        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.add( deckPanel );

        return wrapper;
    }

    private JPanel createStacksPanel()
    {

        stacksPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 4, 10, 10) );
        Dimension stackDimension = new Dimension(cardSize.width, cardSize.height + 200);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            JPanel stackPanel = new JPanel( new OverlapLayout( new Point(0, 20) ) );
            stackPanel.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
            stackPanel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0) );
            stackPanel.setPreferredSize( stackDimension );
            stacksPanel.add( stackPanel );
        }

        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.add( stacksPanel );

        return (wrapper );
    }

    /*
    **  Add the card to the dragging layer so it can be moved
    */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JPanel deckPanel = (JPanel)e.getComponent();
        card =  deckPanel.getComponent( 0 );

        if (card instanceof JPanel) return;

        Point parentLocation = card.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        card.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);

        JLayeredPane lp = getRootPane().getLayeredPane();
        lp.add(card, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    }

    /*
    **  Move the chess piece around
    */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        if (card == null) return;

        int x = me.getX() + xAdjustment;
        int y = me.getY() + yAdjustment;
        card.setLocation(x, y);
     }

    /*
    **  Drop the card back onto the game board
    */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        setCursor(null);

        if (card == null) return;

        //  Make sure the card is no longer painted on the layered pane

        card.setVisible(false);

        //  check to see if card was dragged to a stack

        JPanel stackPanel = null;
        Point localPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), e.getPoint(), stacksPanel);

        for (int i = 0; i < stacksPanel.getComponentCount(); i++)
        {
            JPanel panel = (JPanel)stacksPanel.getComponent(i);

            if (panel.getBounds().contains(localPoint))
            {
                stackPanel = panel;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (stackPanel == null)
            deckPanel.add( card );
        else
            stackPanel.add( card );

        card.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DragCards2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new DragCards2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Both examples use the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) to allow for easy stacking of the cards.